# Microsoft Outlook 2013 People Search changing layout to show phone number

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, address-book

I don't maintain a contact list in Outlook, but all the staff in my organisation are available through the directory and can be searched using the sidebar tool as below.

People Search Tool:

[image]

I find this quite useful for finding peoples phone numbers, but there's a few too many clicks involved : I have to search, click on the results to show the card, then expand the card to get the phone number.

People Search Results Card:

[image]

Is there a way to put the phone number field directly into the search results, or, on the compacted Business Card ?

Answer (score 0):

No direct way, sorry. The only workaround I can see is to import your company directory into your Outlook contacts folder (or create a separate Outlook folder of "Contacts" type). Then you'll be able to search this folder and see phones in the search results.